# Rewrite rule in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an url like

```
http://example.com/test.php?pid=105701
```

I need to remove .php in this url.I have tried a lot but the url has going like this

```
http://example.com/test/?pid=105701
```

In above url go for the directory structure. Not able to access the test.php file

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

Help me on this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you also have a directory named "test" ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make some corrections, you should exclude all cases that contains `.php` also:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite filename.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Return 404 if original request is filename.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: In  URL i have added  test.php redirect to correct path.

Comment: When i remove .php and run they going for directory path

Comment: OK now I've disabled accessing to .php directly please check

Comment: Well just tried in my localhost , it's working like a charm . +1 from me ;) @GeorgeGarchagudashvili

Comment: Thanks bro, glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

First of all turn on the mod_rewrite in apache
then

use this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Edited , @PoobalanCGVAK , try this .. and what is the apache version you are using ? 2.4?